# How to access Openshift mysql via locally installed wamp phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

i am using openshift free tier (3 gears). My scalable app uses PHP and MySQL. But unavailability of phpMyAdmin credentials for 3 gears scalable app it's difficult for me to access Mysql table entries. My question is can **port forward** feature of Openshift is used to access openshift Mysql via locally installed wamp phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If you need to access phpMyAdmin from multiple machines, you may prefer it to be part of you gear. In such a case you may install it as part of your app source code. [Read my post here.](http://novelcode.blogspot.com/2015/05/installing-phpmyadmin-on-openshift.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you open the session with Putty, go to the Connection-->SSH-->Tunneling.

There add a port, for example, 3333. And set as destination the url of your remote mysql server and port, for example: 324324343455435435-yourservices.rhcloud.com:44351. Click on the "Add" button. Save your session and connect.

Once connected you can use whatever the client and connect to localhost on the port 3333 with the user, password and database name given by the env vars as the other guys said. 
I connect with Toad for Mysql with no problems.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to use port forwarding to access your OpenShift database from your locally installed PhpMyAdmin.

First, make sure you have the Redhat Client Tools (RHC) installed on your computer. If you haven't, download them here: https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install .

In order to connect via SSH, you will need a public/private key pair. Again RHC can automate most of this for you when you run `rhc setup`. The application will ask for your credentials, optionally create an SSH key for you and upload it to your cartridges. Make sure to protect your SSH key with a secure password. This process is described in more detail at https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access .

You will need a SSH client. OpenShift recommends Putty for Windows users; detailed setup instructions can be found at https://www.openshift.com/page/install-and-setup-putty-ssh-client-for-windows . In addition I would recommend to install OpenSSH from Cygwin, as this makes it easier to forward the port to your database later on.

Use Putty and your SSH key to connect to your server via SSH. Once you are at the shell, type `env` to view a list of environment variables on the server. Look for the variables that end with `_DB_HOST`, `_DB_PORT`, `_DB_USERNAME` and `_DB_PASSWORD` and make a note of their values on your Windows machine. The names and meanings of all of these environment variables are described at https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Database_Environment_Variables.html .

To forward the port, use Cygwin's `ssh` command. For example:
    ssh -f user@my-app.openshift.com -L 3307:DB_HOST:3306 -N

You will have to replace `user` with your OpenShift username, `my-app.openshift.com` with your public OpenShift hostname and `DB_HOST` with the IP address from the `..._DB_HOST` environment variable that you looked up above. If this command succeeds, you should now have a tunnel from your local port 3307 to the MySQL server at OpenShift. Thus, you can create a new database connection in PhpMyAdmin's configuration with 127.0.0.1 as the server, 3307 as the port and your credentials, which you got when running the `env` command via SSH.

Comment: Thanks claus, But openssh mess window default path.can you please tell what command is used for window rhc client instead of sh -f user@my-app.openshift.com -L 3307:DB_HOST:3306 -N

Comment: The putty package includes a utility called `plink.exe` which is supposed to take the same arguments as `ssh` on non-Windows systems. It is available on the same download page as Putty: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html . Unfortunately I don't have access to a Windows box to test it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rhc port-forward command, similar to what i described here: [OpenShift: How to connect to postgresql from my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960407/openshift-how-to-connect-to-postgresql-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

instead of phpmyadmin.SQLyog from webyog has ssh tunneling option. which work fine for remote accessing openshift mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can add this cartridge to have phpMyAdmin support in scalable apps:

https://github.com/arielscarpinelli/openshift-scalable-phpmyadmin