# Is possible to manage an OpenShift Database with pgAdmin?

Tags: database, postgresql, cloud, openshift, pgadmin

Today I want to know if it is possible to manage a PostgreSQL on OpenShift using pgAdmin, in the same way that we can manage an Amazon RDS database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use port forwarding on your local machine to establish a connection to your remote server:

```
rhc port-forward -a applicationName
```

Now check the output on your command line to which port the postgres database service is mapped, if available this will be `5432` by default.

A step by step documentation about port forwarding is available at [Getting Started with Port Forwarding on OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/).

Comment: [although useful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960407/openshift-how-to-connect-to-postgresql-fro%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bm-my-pc#answer-20965511)

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to configure the ssh-tunnel into your connection.

[image: ssh-tunnel window]

Tunnel-Host would be your applications name

Username the beginning string, when ssh'ing to that connection: **XXX**@application-name

Identity file would be id_rsa in .ssh fodler in your home directory

password your openshift password

Comment: If you use Identity file for authentication (as above) then you must use the passphrase of your id_rsa (private key).