# unable to login remotely in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, openshift, ubuntu-14.04

I am very new to mysql and I want to use remote login I followed this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684341/3985848) process but the command gives me nothing on the screen as listed on that link

```
$ lsof -i -P | grep :3306
$
```

this is the output.

*What I did so far:*
 I edited the file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** to make change and looks like this

```
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

What I want basically that I want remote login.But I am unable to that.
I run following command on my terminal

```
$ mysql -h 127.6.110.2 -u adminTwz5PWn -p
$ enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'adminTwz5PWn'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

*For sake of information needed I got this username and password from Openshift*
 My concern is that how @'localhost' comes into the picture If I am providing the host ip in the command

I have user log in to mysql as follows

```
+------------------+---------------+
| user             | host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| root             | %             |
| root             | 127.0.0.1     |
| adminvKbP1kf     | 127.3.138.130 |
| adminTwz5PWn     | 127.6.110.2   |
| root             | ::1           |
| user             | hostname      |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost     |
| phpmyadmin_suraj | localhost     |
| root             | localhost     |
| suraj            | localhost     |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere. And what steps are needed to make this successfull

Comment: `using password: YES` suggests the password is incorrect. Do you have separate users for `127.0.0.1` and `%` hosts with different passwords?

Comment: Is lsof even installed? Stupid question, but you never know.

Comment: @Orpheus Yes I having lsof I did by sudo apt-get install lsof

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I have ..Please see the edited question.I added users list

Comment: this belongs on dba or [sf].

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenShift: How to connect to postgresql from my PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960407/openshift-how-to-connect-to-postgresql-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this on OpenShift, and trying to connect from your local workstation, you need to use the rhc port-forward command.  Check the answer to a very similar question, but it was using postgresql, you can adapt it very easily to use mysql: [OpenShift: How to connect to postgresql from my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960407/openshift-how-to-connect-to-postgresql-from-my-pc)

Comment: You would use the rhc port-forward command, and connect to the mysql port for your application instead of the postgresql one.

Answer (score 0):

You should first restart the MySQL server

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: It gives me like this ::: Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly.

Comment: Now you try to log in
mysql -h 127.6.110.2 -u XXX -p

Comment: Then kill the mysql service and start it again. 
Do first /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Comment: I followed same as you said but still same

Comment: are you sure that mysql process stopped properly ,

Use kill -9 mysql_process_ID
Then check the status . Do those steps. It should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72080/discussion-between-learner-and-altius).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mysql is not able to resolve your host so it is defaulting to `localhost`. So when looking up permissions for your login, it evaluates `'adminTwz5PWn'@'localhost'` instead of `'adminTwz5PWn'@IP`. I suspect that problem has something to do with the bind address `0.0.0.0`. Try changing the bind address to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` and see what happens.