# Connect to Openshift Mongodb remotely with Java, timeout error

Tags: java, mongodb, openshift

I have turn on the port-forward with rhc, it shows
mongodb 127.0.0.1:27017 => xxx.x.xxx.x:27017
doc here [port-forward](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/)

but I still have no luck connect to that mongodb cartridge. I've try both mongo shell 3.0 and java MongoClient.
mongo shell return error 10061
java return `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}`

what else could I try to connect to openshift mongodb remotely?

my code, I've test this on local mongodb which works fine

```
    String mongoUri = "mongodb://admin:password@xxx.x.xxx.x:27017/";                        
    MongoClient mongoClient;
    try {

        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri));

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mycoll");

        DBCollection cc = db.getCollection("DBObject");
        cc.insert(dbo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following connection string locally while you have port forwarding enabled:

```
String mongoUri = "mongodb://admin:password@127.0.0.1:27017/";
```

Since the connection is being forwarded over an ssh tunnel, you need to use the local port.  See this answer for more information: [OpenShift: How to connect to postgresql from my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960407/openshift-how-to-connect-to-postgresql-from-my-pc)

Comment: connecting locally is working, but what I want is to connect remotely.

Comment: You will be connecting remotely, that ip/port that shows up when you do a port forward gets forwarded to the remote server.

Comment: that's what I thought, but when I actually run my code, it gives me errno 10061